# Date Format in form page using Rails 4 with Haml

Tags: ruby, haml

I am using Rails 4.1.6 and Ruby 2.1.5 and for view I am using `html.haml` file.
In Form Page I want input date format should be in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

For this in in `config/locales/en.yml` file i have:

```
date:
    formats:
      long: ! '%-m/%-d/%Y'
```

In `_form.html.haml` I have:

```
f.input :date_of_birth,:input_html =>{:format => :long}
```

The problem I have is it's not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
 = f.input :date_of_birth, :value => t(@model.date_of_birth,:format => :long)
```

Comment: Its not working. 1 more thing i am using postgres and in that date_of_birth column format is yyyy-mm-dd.